# Apparently damaged external disk drivers. Can they be repaired?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), and about a month ago I tried to enable NTFS read/write with some guides on the internet. Crucially I can't remember which guides I followed.

It didn't work, however I noticed that I can no longer mount any **MAC OS** external drive (USB stick, USB external hard disk, SD Card), regardless of the formatting.

I can see all these drives fine with 'Disk Utility' but I simply can not mount them. I've tried mounting from the terminal as well, but I really get no error message at all. I have another MacBook Pro (without my NTFS adventure) and the drives all work fine.

Is there any way I can repair the disk drivers? I would really prefer not to have to reinstall my system (especially now file backup isn't possible!)

Note : Currently running macOS Sierra v 10.12.4

Comment: Basically there are two free methods to enable write access to NTFS: fstab & ntfs-3g. So check whether /etc/fstab and/or /sbin/mount_ntfs.original & /sbin/mount_ntfs exist.

Comment: Thanks @klanomath - I will look, but my problem is that no disks are working any more, including MAC OS ones

Comment: If you don't remember the guide, you/we have to narrow it down systematically. NTFS is the first step. Checking mod dates (~April, 1 2017) of various system or bin/sbin folders is the next one.